# How can we used REST and RPC as an integrated framework?

Tags: rest, rpc

I am setting up a framework in which biometric authentication can be done through web services in service oriented architecture. Furthermore,  BIAS is working with SOAP but I want to make it compatible with REST AND RPC.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more of a conceptual question that belongs on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com instead. Please consider asking your questions there instead.

Comment: `REST` and `RPC` are no frameworks; shuffling terms leads exactly nowhere... voted to close it for "too broad" because neither `BIAS` was defined and it seems that no previous effort or research is involved.